# The same char is being displayed in infinite loop

Tags: c, keyboard, kernel, infinite-loop

I'm following this tutorials:

http://wiki.osdev.org/Keyboard

http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Zesterer/Bare_Bones

I'm trying to add keyboard support, but I've ended up in point where if I press one character for example **'A'** the program keeps showing thousands of **'A'** until I press another key for example **'1'**(it's showing thousands of **'1'** too until I press another key, and so forth). I want to place characters one by one, I mean if **'A'** is pressed once it displays it once and it still lets me add another characters.

```
//Places single char onto the screen
void term_putc(char c);


//Provides the scancode from kb controller
char getScancode(){
char c=0;
do {
if(inb(0x60) != c)
{
c=inb(0x60);
if(c>0)
return c;
}
}while(1);}

//transfroms scancodes to chars
char getchar();

//shows the character on the screen
void kb_print(){ 
char chara = getchar(); // Pressed key value
term_putc(chara);
}
```

Now I'm calling out main function

```
void kernel_main(){
term_init();

while(1){
    kb_print();
}
}
```

Whole code:

```
https://pastebin.com/CMNvZN3P
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: mess in code? you forgot to add the code to the question

Comment: 1.) add code *directly* in the question, 2.) for this, create a [mcve] first.

Comment: I hope it's correct now :)

Comment: Try `while(!(inb(0x64) & 2)) ; return inb(0x60);` in `getScancode()`. This will wait for the keyboard buffer to become non-empty before reading the scancode.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. The `getScancode` is a mess.

Comment: @IanAbbott `while(!(inb(0x64) & 2)) ; return inb(0x60);` in `getScancode()` gives same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found second best solution. 
I used this function:

```
// Sends a 8/16/32-bit value on a I/O location
static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val){
  asm volatile ( "outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port) );
```

Placed

```
outb(0x60, 0x0);
```

in

```
char getScancode(){

  char c=0;
  outb(0x60, 0x0);
  do{
    if(inb(0x60) != c){
      c=inb(0x60);
      if(c>0)
      return c;
    }
  }while(1);
}
```

For some reasons port 0x60 was not empty after keypress. (If it should)